# get NSString first word only

Tags: objective-c

I am having this `NSString`, that gives me the user language .

```
NSString * language= @"English (America) " ;
```

I need to get from it ONLY the first word- which is the language .
I know how to find space, but could not find a simple way to get only the first word.

ThAnks.

Comment: Do you really want the first word? Consider "Traditional Chinese". Maybe the part before the brackets?

Comment: :) Yes thanks a lot. i need only 5 languages, and i know what they are so in any other way -i will probably use English :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
NSString *firstWord = [[language componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: The answer is correct. The question may be flawed :D This will always give the word before the first space but that may not be what he is after. :-) Nikolai's answer will probably suit this specific need :D

Comment: like I said, this answers the question asked. But the question asked was possibly not correct :D

Comment: I assume that the i get the right language from the NSLocal .

Answer (score 6):

```
NSUInteger location = [language rangeOfString:@" ("].location;
NSString *result = location == NSNotFound ? language : [language substringToIndex:location];
```

Comment: This is obviously assuming there'll also be a "(", and won't capture the first word if it's not the case.

Comment: @WDUK Correct. I proposed this in a comment to the question.

Comment: this is much faster than componentsSeparatedByString. You can see the difference when you use this on a uitableview. Maybe because this returns the actual string needed and the componentsSeparatedByString returns an NSArray.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer:

```
  NSString * language= @"English (America) " ;

  NSArray *comps = [language componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

  NSString * eng = [comps objectAtIndex:0];
```